# Blazor Component Conditional DEBUG statement

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to have a DEBUG statement for the compiler that can apply to the attributes? I am wanting to do something like this:

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

#if DEBUG
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Developer")]
#else
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "HR Admin")]
#endif

<h1>Primary Header</h1>

@code {
    ... code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this within the `.razor` file. If you create a code behind file (`.razor.cs`) you can then move the `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Developer")]` to the code behind file.

```cs
#if (DEBUG)
    [Authorize(Roles = "Developer")]
#else
    [Authorize(Roles = "HR Admin")]
#endif
    public partial class SomePage
    {
        ...
    }
```

I personally use policy based auth. This becomes a lot easier as you can do this sort of thing within the policy.

**TIP**: If you are using Visual Studio click on the `@code` wait for the light bulb to appear -> "Extract block to code behind"

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about the Policy feature for the authorization. Works out great. I was using the format of my question for my MVC IActionResult methods and Controllers. It is a little bit of a learning curve going from MVC to Blazor.